# How to keep an :active css style after clicking a link?

Tags: html, css, fonts, icons

I need help with creating an :active style after the icon has been clicked. I am using Font-awesome icons, and can't workout how to keep the icon a certain colour after the icon has been clicked, any help would be great, Thanks

HTML Nav table:

```
<table width="100" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="59"><li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-university fa-lg "></i></li></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="59"><li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i></li></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="59"> <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-lg"></i></li></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="59"><li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-comments fa-lg"></i></li></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td height="59"><li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-lg"></i></li></td>
          </tr>
```

The CSS to create a colour hover over:

```
    .fa-university:hover {
color: white;
transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById("target").onclick=function () {//Detects a click on #target

  if (this.classList) {//check if classlist is supported
     this.classList.add("newcolor");//add the class
  } else {
    this.class += " newcolor";//if classlist isn't supported, add " newcolor" to the attribute value
  }
}
```

```css
#target {
  width: 50px;height: 50px;
  background-color:red;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.newcolor {
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Foo</div>
```

This in simple terms, adds a new class with new values to the element after it has been clicked.